# stocking api response.data in localStorage on click vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My goal is to store a specific data in the `localStorage` when I click on a link

but log i get is either undefined or absolutely nothing.

```html
<li v-for="(categorie, index) in categories" :key="index">   
                <a href="./currentCategory" @click.prevent="getCategory()"> 
                       
              <img class="categorie-img" :src="categorie.strCategoryThumb" >    
              <p>{{ categorie.strCategory }}</p>
            </a>
            </li>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      categories: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getAllCategories() {
      axios
        .get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log( response.data);
          this.categories = response.data.categories;  
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert("api can't be reached");
        })
    },
    getCategory() {
        localStorage.setItem('currentCategory', this.categorie.strCategory );
    }
  },
```

I am using this API https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php

I guess  `this.categorie.strCategory` is incorrect but i really cant figure it out

I also tried `this.categories.strCategory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass category

```
@click.prevent="getCategory(categorie)
```

then save it

```
getCategory(cat) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentCategory', cat );
}
```

Comment: i get this error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: cat is not defined```

Comment: @Azciop hey mate sorry, my bad, `categorie` instead `category` :)

Comment: no worries :D ! i get this in the localstorage ```[object Object]```  but i changed categorie to categorie.strCategory and now its working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic I think it should be stored as a string in a localStorage `JSON.stringify(cat)`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to @Nikola Pavicevic

had to pass a category to the click event

```html
@click.prevent="getCategory(categorie.strCategory)
```

and pass it to the function

```js
getCategory(cat) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentCategory', cat);
    }
```